# Which way would be faster to process?

Tags: php, mysql, json

**A lil background info**

At the moment I have a script that parses a page on a site (not controlled by me) into a mysql database for a game (Getting ingame attack logs). I've recently decided I wanted to upgrade this faster and I've completely recoded the parser so that it stores the data into an array. Now onto the basis of my question:

My first version currently has around 50 columns, one for each unit times by how many a user lost/has left and a few other bits and pieces - these often go unused if the user doesn't actually lose a unit or doesn't loose a unit of that type. Now if I was to JSON encode the array and literally stick that into the database

1) will that be faster than the current one when inserting?

2) Lets say I need to get that data back on the front page and show 100 results(Only a summary is needed so only 3 columns selected on the first way), if I was to do the first way I could show the data with one select and while loop it, would that be slower or faster than me selecting it from the db, then decoding it and processing it?

(Also if you know of a better way, don't hesitate to say :) - or if I should do a mix of the two)

Comment: I would like to point you out to this very interesting read: http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't so much with the inserting, which you only do once per record - but in the reading. You will lose of all MySQLs data-processing powers as you will just have a JSON lump sat in a big text field.

It would be much more performant to be able to select the records you need from the database using a MySQL query than it would be getting all records from the database and looping around them in memory.

Comment: True, but for example, I have a leaderboards page that selects every row/column in the database, this db is arounds 30k rows big. I then have to select all of it and use that. Is that not slower than having a json var in one part of the text feild? I was thinking that stuff Id use for summaries etc Id put in there own column (like name of user etc) and the json would be for the huge data.

Comment: (Forgot to notify you ^_^) Also thanks for the spelling edit, awful at English even though its my primary language.

Comment: The beauty of having it all in MySQL is that you can use an aggregate to calculate the score, order the results and only return the top "n" leaders for the leaderboard. You don't want to send too much data to the page for processing.

Comment: Unfortunatly I dont think I could use a Aggregate function (since the calculations are really complex and require calculating accross rows depending on a static array in my php code). Im probably only leaning towards the json route because of the task of making a new table with loads of columns doesnt sound very fun hehe. Okay then Ill stick to using just mysql then. Thanks for your responses.